# No error: PDO constructor was not called in

Tags: php, pdo

Good afternoon. I'm starting using the PDO yesterday, and I have some problem with this. I was creating extendet class, which doesn't work and I can't find the bug.

This is code of my helper class, for work witch PDO:

```
    class EPDO extends PDO {
  /** Some identificator of connection*/
  public $db;

  /**
   * Creating new PDO connections
   */     
  public function __construct($dbhost, $dbname, $dbuser = 'root', $dbpass = '', $dbtype = 'mysql') {
    $db = new PDO($dbtype . ':host=' . $dbhost . ';dbname=' . $dbname, $dbuser, $dbpass);
  } 

  /**
   * Insert into database with using transaction (if operation failed the changes go before)
   */     
  public function insert($statement) {
    $db->beginTransaction();

    $status = $db->exec($statement);
    if ($status) {
      $db->commit();  
    } else {
      $db->rollback();
    }
  } 
}
```

And this is the unfunctional code:

```
$stm = $db->prepare('SELECT id FROM `startups` WHERE id = :id');
$params = array(':id' => $child->id);
$ok = $stm->execute($params);
$row = $stm->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Before this code I of course call the connections following way:

```
  require_once 'EPDO.php';

  try {
    $db = new EPDO('--server--', '--database--', '--user--', '--pass--');
  }
  catch (PDOException $err) {
    echo "Chyba spojeni: " . $err->getMessage();
  }
```

Thank you very much, and sorry for my english.

Comment: Can you explain `which doesn't work ` means.?What error do you get.?

Comment: This line call to me (on line 15 is variable $stm):                                                Warning: PDO::prepare() [pdo.prepare]: SQLSTATE[00000]: No error: PDO constructor was not called in /data/web/virtuals/2286/virtual/www/subdom/map/sm/GetStartups.php on line 15

Fatal error: Call to a member function execute() on a non-object in /data/web/virtuals/2286/virtual/www/subdom/map/sm/GetStartups.php on line 17

Comment: You need to refer to the class variable `$db` within your class methods as `$this->db`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that you're extending the `PDO` class and overriding the constructor, all without calling the constructor.

Additionally, you're essentially creating two database connections every time you create a new object.

This should help resolve your issue, and reduce the connections created:

```
class EPDO extends PDO {
    /** Some identificator of connection*/
    public $db;

    /**
     * Creating new PDO connections
     */     
    public function __construct($dbhost, $dbname, $dbuser = 'root', $dbpass = '', $dbtype = 'mysql') {
        parent::__construct($dbtype . ':host=' . $dbhost . ';dbname=' . $dbname, $dbuser, $dbpass);
    } 

    /**
     * Insert into database with using transaction (if operation failed the changes go before)
     */     
    public function insert($statement) {
        $this->beginTransaction();
        $status = $this->exec($statement);
        if ($status) {
            $this->commit();  
        } else {
            $this->rollback();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Two problems: your design is wrong. You extend PDO, yet you create a new member object `$db` of type PDO inside. That won't work as you intend it. You'll have to call its super constructor.

```
public function __construct($dbhost, $dbname, $dbuser = 'root', $dbpass = '', $dbtype = 'mysql') {
      parent::__construct($dbtype . ':host=' . $dbhost . ';dbname=' . $dbname, $dbuser, $dbpass);
}
```

In fact, this constructor isn't needed at all, you are just changing the parameters, creating confusion. So you can easily remove it, together with the `$db` attribute.

Second, to refer to class members and methods, use [`$this` in PHP](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php):

```
public function insert($statement) {
    $this->beginTransaction();

    $status = $this->exec($statement);
    if ($status) {
      $this->commit();  
    } else {
      $this->rollback();
    }
}
```

Comment: I updated my answer. There are two issues with your code and design.

Answer (score 1):

All these long answers, when the solution is so simple:

You have to use

```
$this->db = new PDO(...
```

instead of

```
$db = new PDO(...
```

Because when you hit

```
$db->commit();
```

`$db` is empty = constructor not called.

The error message should be something like `undefined method commit() on non-object`.
You also have to use

```
$this->db->commit();
```

**Use `$this` on every member and method accessed from inside the class**

and so on...