# Using PDO database connection class to fetch data

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

```
class dbconnect extends PDO {
  private $dbengine   = 'mysql';
  private $dbhost     = 'localhost';
  private $dbuser     = 'root';
  private $dbpassword = 'root';
  private $dbname     = 'nesiojami';
  public $dbh = null;

  public function __construct() {
    try {
      $pdo = $this->dbh = new PDO("".$this->dbengine.":host=$this->dbhost; dbname=$this->dbname", $this->dbuser, $this->dbpassword);
      $pdo = $this->dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE, PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
    }
    catch (PDOException $e) {
      $e->getMessage();
    }
  }
}
```

This is how I connecting to the database.

```
$clients = $pdo->query("SELECT client-name, client-surname FROM clients")->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

And I can't find a way how to fetch data with my connection to the database.

Answer (score 0):

call the PDO constructor in construct function of dbconnect class

```
$con= dbconnect new ();

$clients = $con->query("SELECT client-name, client-surname FROM clients")->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Read this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20284396/no-error-pdo-constructor-was-not-called-in) for more info

Comment: I'm still getting error.
Warning: PDO::query(): SQLSTATE[00000]: No error: PDO constructor was not called in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/application/init.php on line 31

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function fetchAll() on null in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/application/init.php:31 Stack trace: #0 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/clients.php(3): require_once() #1 {main} thrown in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/application/init.php on line 31

Comment: @ErikasR Follow the link, you will need a little bit modification of your code, you are close

Answer (score 0):

```
class DbConnect extends PDO {
    private $dbengine   = 'mysql';
    private $dbhost     = 'localhost';
    private $dbuser     = 'root';
    private $dbpassword = 'root';
    private $dbname     = 'nesiojami';
    public $dbh = null;

    public function __construct() {
        try {
            // since you are extending PDO, you have to call its constructor
            parent::connect($this->dbengine.":host=$this->dbhost; dbname=$this->dbname", $this->dbuser, $this->dbpassword);
            $this->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE, PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
        }
        catch (PDOException $e) {
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }
    }
}
```

Use it like this:

```
$pdo = new DbConnect;
$clients = $pdo->query("SELECT client-name, client-surname FROM clients")->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```